# on latest angular 2, using jspm, can't minify bundle

Tags: angular, uglifyjs, jspm

on latest angular 2, using jspm, can't minify bundle...

getting an error of

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
    at createError (C:\msweb\studioDashboard\node_modules\gulp-uglify\lib\create-error.js:6:14)
    at wrapper (C:\msweb\studioDashboard\node_modules\lodash\_createHybrid.js:87:15)
    at trycatch (C:\msweb\studioDashboard\node_modules\gulp-uglify\minifier.js:26:12)
```

used to work fine and broke on recent update to ng 2.0,

any info on this is appreciated

thanks,

Sean.

Comment: this might happen when there is error in javascript files. have to tried minifying any simple javascript file if it is working fine there is no problem with the minifier

Comment: the entire project is typescript, and no errors.

Answer (score 1):

after spending 2 days trying to fix jspm with bundling I was finally able to fix it, in jspm you need to remove from packages the statement of :

`packages: {
 "@angular/common": {
            "main": "index.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/compiler": {
            "main": "index.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/core": {
            "main": "index.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/http": {
            "main": "index.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/platform-browser": {
            "main": "index.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": {
            "main": "index.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/router": {
            "main": "index.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        }
        ...`

I have no idea what changed in ng2 prior to rc.6 that would require this removel, but here you go, this fixes it and now I can FINALLY run:

`jspm bundle app/main ./dist/index.js --minify --skip-source-maps`

hopes it helps someone

Sean